# Unable to click on a button within a frame - VBA Selenium ChromeDriver

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriver

I'm currently struggling with a problem concerning click on a button through Selenium and ChromeDriver. I'm currently coding in Excel-VBA.

I tried the same code on dozen of other websites and it worked. I have a problem only in the following one. 
I tried to locate the button trough CSS Selector, XPath, Name, to run a JS but nothing worked, so I'm here to beg your help. 
I also tried to add implicit and explicit wait, imagine, nothing worked.
 Currently, I'm out of option.
I would like to click on the RESET button

```
Dim driver As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
Set driver = CreateObject("Selenium.ChromeDriver")

driver.Get "https://www.prova.html"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
driver.Window.Maximize
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
driver.ExecuteScript ("window.scrollTo(0, 360)")
driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[5]/input[2]").Click
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you get an error message at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the `iframe` element that is present on the page -- the button you are trying to click is contained in an `iframe` element, so you need to switch to the frame before you can interact with the button.

```
// switch to frame
driver.SwitchToFrame(driver.FindElementByXPath("//iframe[@id='frame']"))

// locate RESET button
driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[@value='Reset']").Click
```

Comment: I missed the `driver.` call inside the `SwitchToFrame`, just kinda blanked on the syntax there. I've updated my answer accordingly, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thank you very much! in my computer works with this syntax: ```driver.SwitchToFrame driver.FindElementByXPath("//iframe[@id='frame']")``` Thanks without you I couldn't have done it ;)

Answer (score 0):

The element with text as **RESET** is within an `<iframe>` so you need to `SwitchToFrame()` first and then locate the desired button and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  Dim driver As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
  Set driver = CreateObject("Selenium.ChromeDriver")

  driver.Get "https://www.merkur-win.it/scommesse.html"
  driver.Window.Maximize
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
  driver.SwitchToFrame "frame"
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
  driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[@class='sport_resetgiocata']").Click
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much! it works perfectly! I just learned something new, I'm so sure that could help me in several other occasions! thank you again